# Keep row and column headers visible while scrolling in Numbers

Tags: numbers

Numbers has this nice feature of marking e.g. the first row and column of a table as the headers of the rows/columns.

Now when I have a lot of rows/columns and scroll down or right, those headers disappear. So it is not always clear what row/column a certain cell belongs to.

Google Sheets has this nice feature of keeping the headers of a row/column locked at the screen so you keep seeing it whenever you scroll down.

How can I replicate this behavior in Apple Numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-, or <kbd>control</kbd> click the header row and select "Freeze Header Rows", or "Feeze Header Columns" respectively.

Also found under the menu "Table > Freeze Header Rows"/ "Freeze Header Columns".

Comment: You also need to set the number of header rows or colums as the default is 0